# How do I get the last cell in a row of a DataTable?

Tags: c#

```
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
       foreach(var cell in row.ItemArray)
       {
          builder.Append(cell.ToString());
          if(cell != row.lastcell)
             builder.Append("\t");
       }
       builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

i need to make sure that cell!=the last cell in the row

how do i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do that. Just use `string.Join` instead:

```
string[] strings = Array.ConvertAll(row.ItemArray, x => x.ToString());
builder.Append(string.Join("\t", strings);
```

Comment: this is a much preferred way as its cleaner and keeps brevity

Answer (score 0):

This would get you the last row:

```
row = (DataRow)table.Rows[table.Rows.Count-1];
```

Comment: @i dont need the last row, i need the last cell in the row

Comment: @herrow switch the Rows for column

Answer (score 0):

You could completely avoid the last cell if you use a for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<row.ItemArray-2;i++)
{
    // do your code here, we are taking off the last cell with the -2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use row.ItemArray[row.ItemArray.Length-1] to get a value of last cell

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   string separator = String.Empty;
   foreach(var cell in row.ItemArray)
   {
      builder.Append(separator);
      builder.Append(cell.ToString());
      separator  = "\t";
   }
   builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```